# Python 3 gives NaN for operation that Python 2 handles

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scipy

The calculation I'm trying with [`scipy.stats.hypergeom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) is giving `nan` when run in Python 3.9.9 but works fine in Python 2.7.18. I need it to run it in Python 3 because the rest of my program is for that version.

I've tried casting all of the numbers to the same float type and rounding the numbers but nothing seems to make it work for Python 3. I've included my code and the outputs I get for the different versions.

#### Code

```py
from scipy.stats import hypergeom

k   = 526.8499999999999
nmk = 409.823
n   = 936.6729999999999
m   = 30079.555399999997
N   = 59416.2896

p1 = hypergeom.cdf(k, N, m, n)
p2 = hypergeom.cdf(nmk, N, m, n)

print("p1 = " + str(p1) + " [" + str(type(p1)) + "]")
print("p2 = " + str(p2) + " [" + str(type(p2)) + "]")
```

#### Python 2.7.18

```
p1 = 0.999720238917 [<type 'numpy.float64'>]
p2 = 9.96805760427e-06 [<type 'numpy.float64'>]
```

#### Python 3.9.9

```
p1 = nan [<class 'numpy.float64'>]
p2 = nan [<class 'numpy.float64'>]
```

---

**Edit:** The `scipy` version I'm using is 0.13.0b1 for Python 2 and 1.8.0 for Python 3.

Comment: I am running Python 3.8.12 and I am able to get your Python 2.7.18 output. Is downgrading to another version of Python 3 possible for you. (Also, my scipy version is 1.5.1 btw)

Comment: It is more likely that the reason is the version of `scipy` (or one of its dependencies) than the version of Python

Comment: Did some testing across versions - the script works in scipy 1.7.3, but breaks in the next version of 1.8.0rc1 (all in Python 3.9.9). I have a feeling it might be related to [this PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/14153).

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Downgrading to scipy 1.7.3 worked.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you file an issue over at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading `scipy` from version 1.8.0 to 1.7.3 solved this issue.